# how to create An app in twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I'm new in this ... I followed this steps

http://iag.me/socialmedia/how-to-create-a-twitter-app-in-8-easy-steps/

but i don't know what's the exact URL i should write it ? i found different URLs on different examples .. but i don't have one !

and i read if i don't have URL yet i should put placeholder !! what's the placeholder ?

and what's the callback URL

i hope someone help me on this .

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in article http://sgeek.org/how-to-create-twitter-app-in-4-easy-steps/

Answer (score 0):

While creating app in twitter you have to specify your website URL, if you dont have any you can put any URL which refers your identity (like linkedIn public profile URL).

Coming to the callback URL, it tells where to navigate right after login with twitter credentials in your app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i put URL of Facebook profile but i want to know what the benefits of URLs ? what is the usage of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Twitter Appliation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) with the Read and write access permissions and Organization or personal website for callback url in Application.